# ValueError: when defining sparse input with dense layer

Tags: tensorflow

I want to feed a sparse tensor into a dense layer

```
inputs1 = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 500], name='input1')
model1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=inputs1, units=128, name='dense1')
```

When I execute this I get the following error

```
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`
```

If I change sparse_placeholder to regular place_holder I don't get this error.

Comment: `print( inputs1.get_shape() )` outputs (?, ?) instead of the correct (?, 500). Might be a TensorFlow bug. Was mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6749#issuecomment-297891681)

Comment: It prints TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(500)])

Comment: What version of TensorFlow do you use? On 1.8.0 these two lines:  `inputs1 = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 500], name='input1')  
print( inputs1.get_shape() )  `  do print `( ?, ? )`. Tested on colab.research.google.com.

Comment: @PeterSzoldan. I realized that I made mistake when posted the question. With sparse_placeholder it prints (?, ?). I use 1.8.0.  As a workaround I create the dense layer by hand.  Should I file a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use FeatureColumn when you try to do this. First create a column representing your sparse tensor, then build an input layer. Finally, feed this input layer to your dense layer. This will help your code make your intention clear; do you want this to be a one-hot tensor? do you want embeddings? etc.